# HTML5 Canvas Animation Effect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Please take a look at this website.  https://www.ethereum.org/

There is a nice animation playing in background. What would you call it and how can I make one?

I'm still looking for any samples, tutorials on the subject. and so far I could find is this.
[Motion graphic typeface demo](http://codepen.io/ara_node/pen/nuJCG)

I am still tinkering with the code but without any clear direction, I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried to /Inspect Element/ in your developer tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are 2 html5 Canvas-based directions for you to explore.**

This could be done in html canvas using a 3D context (WebGL).

WebGL:

- simulates 3D objects using html5 canvas.
- Allows you to create a shape similar to your example link.
- Allows you to apply textures to the shape (or just leave the shape as a wireframe).
- Allows you to transform the shape (move, rotate, scale)

Here's an example using threeJS, a popular 3D lib:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes

If the browser(s) you intend to deploy on don't yet support webgl, you can use 2D context to simulate simple 3D graphics:

Here's an example using python to simulate 3D using a 2D context:

http://codentronix.com/2011/04/20/simulation-of-3d-point-rotation-with-python-and-pygame/

Comment: Thank you. Three.js sounds promising. I will try using that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a canvas in the example you linked to but a video tag.